# What's the right way to keep a Docker container alive? (uWSGI related)

Tags: docker, uwsgi

Noob here. So I'm trying to deploy a web application using AWS + docker + nginx + uWSGI + flask. As far as I know, a docker container must have some sort of foreground job to keep itself alive, otherwise it will kill itself after execution.

I've noticed that uWSGI, when not running as a daemon, is a foreground process so I thought I could use that to keep my container alive. Problem is, once it's running on foreground there is absolutely no way to go back to the shell... (plz lmk if I'm wrong here!) which means I can't exec into my container and run commands on it whenever I need server maintenance.

I've seen practices where you just keep a dummy processing running, echoing a simple string every few seconds or so. But this looks kind of clunky -- Is this really the desirable approach? If it is, is there a better idea of a dummy process than echoing that could possibly keep my console a little bit cleaner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You start the container running your main command that will stay alive for the lifetime of the container. You launch the container usually in the background as not to block, like `docker run -d -t image --name container ...`. Later when you want to play around inside the container, you can `exec` into it `docker exec -it container bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker image is created using Docker file and in Docker file you specify the steps needed to create the image, You noticed the last instruction in Docker file is usually a `CMD` when you run an image using this command `docker run image-name` docker executes the command you specified in `CMD` in container and if this command ends, your container stops. but you can replace this command with something else like `docker run -it image-name bash` this command gives you an interactive shell and if you exit from it(terminate it) your container also stops.(you replaced the last command you specified in `CMD` with `bash` here)

`docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash` : this command is when you want to start an interactive shell in a **running container**

Comment: if I am too way off please inform me and I will delete this :)

Answer (score 2):

you can get into every running container with a bash with:

```
docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash
```

[image]

Comment: I still wouldn't be able to run any commands inside the container because uWSGI is running foreground, and I can't find a way to head back to the container bash.

Comment: you can start a second parallel to the one which already started.

Or do you need exact the bash from the main-process?